# iPhone is dead, will not charge

Tags: battery, iphone, charging

I have an iPhone 4s running on iOS 8.1.3. I've owned it for about 2-3 years now and have taken good care of it physically and hardware wise. But recently my phone had died. I plugged it in to the charger no problem right? I come back about 20 minutes later to see nothing had changed... I tried adjusting the cord, trying to power down the device, rebooting, safe mode, and just letting it sit without the cord and retrying to charge it. Nothing worked; the phone just kept blinking the red battery logo even of 1 entire day of charging. What is there to do?

Comment: Is it dead, battery wise? Could it be the cord or plug, or even the outlet/strip?

Comment: You likely need to replace the battery.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few possible things that could have happened. I've ordered them (and their solutions) below from most to least likely.

#### Explanations:

1. You have a faulty cord.

   - It has become frayed on the inside.
   - One of the metallic connectors is dirty.
2. Dust or dirt has collected in your charging port.
3. Your wall outlet is not functioning correctly.
4. You have a hardware problem.

   - Your charging port has become disconnected internally.
   - Your battery is defective.

Many of these cause your device not to charge. Thus, powering on your device does nothing.

#### Solutions:

1. [Get a new cord](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?field-keywords=iPhone+4s+30+pin+USB+cable).

   - Manually repair the wire by [soldering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soldering) the frayed ends together and using a [heat-shrink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat-shrink_tubing) to put everything back together. (You probably just want to buy a new cord.)
   - Clean the dirty connectors.
2. [Clean out your charging port](http://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/how-to-clean-lint-from-iphone-and-ipad-ports) with a folded index card, toothpick, plastic card, etc.
3. Call an [electrician](https://www.google.com/search?q=electricians).
4. [Take your device in to get fixed](https://www.apple.com/support/iphone/repair/). (Hopefully, you have a warranty.)